# Java object LinkedList attribute: only receiving the first element on server-side using TCP

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serializable, objectinputstream

A little bit of context: the client is sending to the server a SOSPFPacket object (via TCP) that has various attributes, such as a `Vector<LSA> lsaArray`. The `LSA` itself has a `LinkedList<LinkDescription> links` attribute. In my test case, there are two messages being sent. In both messages, there is only one `LSA` in the vector. In the first message, the LSA has one LinkDescription, in the second, it has two. When I send a message, I increment the `messageId`.

The server receives both messages with proper ids, but in the second message, the links only contain one link instead of two. I'm clueless...

Here are the object implementations:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SOSPFPacket implements Serializable {
  public final static short HELLO = 0;
  public final static short LSU = 1;
  public final static short OVER_BURDENED = 2;
  public static int id = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

  public String srcProcessIP;
  public short srcProcessPort;
  public String srcIP;
  public String dstIP;
  public short sospfType; //0 - HELLO, 1 - LinkState Update, 2 - Over Burdened
  public String routerID;
  public int messageId = id++;
  public String neighborID; //neighbor's simulated IP address
  public Vector<LSA> lsaArray = new Vector<>();
  public String lsaInitiator = null;
}
```

---

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LSA implements Serializable {
  public String linkStateID;
  public int lsaSeqNumber = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  public LinkedList<LinkDescription> links = new LinkedList<LinkDescription>();

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(linkStateID + ":").append(lsaSeqNumber + "\n");
    for (LinkDescription ld : links) {
      sb.append(ld);
    }
    sb.append("\n");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class LinkDescription implements Serializable {
  public String linkID;
  public int portNum;
  public int tosMetrics;

  public LinkDescription() {}

  public LinkDescription(String linkID, int portNum, int tosMetrics) {
    this.linkID = linkID;
    this.portNum = portNum;
    this.tosMetrics = tosMetrics;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return linkID + ","  + portNum + "," + tosMetrics;
  }
}
```

---

To send the message, I do it via a `Client.java` thread implementing `Runnable`. Here are the relevant methods:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        _outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(_clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        sendMessage(SOSPFPacket.HELLO);
        _inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(_clientSocket.getInputStream());
        SOSPFPacket message = Util.receiveMessage(_inputStream);

        if (message.sospfType == SOSPFPacket.OVER_BURDENED) {
            System.out.println("Removing link with router " + message.srcIP + "...");
            _router.removeLink(_remoteRouterIP);
            return;
        }

        _remoteRouterDescription.setStatus(RouterStatus.TWO_WAY);
        _router.addLinkDescriptionToDatabase(_remoteRouterDescription, _link.getWeight());
        sendMessage(SOSPFPacket.HELLO);
        message = Util.receiveMessage(_inputStream);

        if (message.sospfType == SOSPFPacket.LSU) {
            _router.synchronize(message.lsaArray);
        }

        _router.propagateSynchronization(message.lsaInitiator, message.srcIP);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendMessage(short messageType) {
    try {
        SOSPFPacket message = Util.makeMessage(_rd, _remoteRouterDescription, messageType, _router);
        _outputStream.writeObject(message);
        _outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Util {
    public static SOSPFPacket makeMessage(RouterDescription local, RouterDescription external, short messageType, Router rd) {
        SOSPFPacket message = new SOSPFPacket();
        message.srcProcessIP = local.getProcessIPAddress();
        message.srcProcessPort = local.getProcessPortNumber();
        message.srcIP = local.getSimulatedIPAddress();
        message.dstIP = external.getSimulatedIPAddress();
        message.sospfType = messageType;
        message.routerID = local.getSimulatedIPAddress();
        message.neighborID = external.getSimulatedIPAddress();
        rd.getLsd().getStore().forEach((k, v) -> message.lsaArray.addElement(v));
        message.lsaInitiator = messageType == SOSPFPacket.LSU ? message.srcIP : null;

        return message;
    }

    public static SOSPFPacket receiveMessage(ObjectInputStream inputStream) {
        SOSPFPacket receivedMessage = null;

        try {
            receivedMessage = (SOSPFPacket) inputStream.readObject();

            String messageType;

            switch (receivedMessage.sospfType) {
                case SOSPFPacket.HELLO:
                    messageType = "HELLO";
                    break;
                case SOSPFPacket.LSU:
                    messageType = "LINKSTATEUPDATE";
                    break;
                case SOSPFPacket.OVER_BURDENED:
                    messageType = "OVER_BURDENED";
                    break;
                default:
                    messageType = "UNKNOWN_STATE";
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println("received " + messageType + " from " + receivedMessage.srcIP + ";");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No message received.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return receivedMessage;
    }
}
```

---

And the server instantiates a private `ClientServiceThread` when it receives a new connection, which is in charge of receiving the message.

```
private class ClientServiceThread implements Runnable {
    Socket _clientSocket;
    Thread _runner;

    ClientServiceThread(Socket s) {
        _clientSocket = s;
        _runner = new Thread(this);
    }

    public Thread getRunner() { return _runner; }

    public void run() {
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(_clientSocket.getInputStream());
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(_clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                try {
                    SOSPFPacket receivedMessage = Util.receiveMessage(inputStream);

                    //some logic not relevant since the receivedMessage is already not correct
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, all `SOSPFPacket` fields are correctly received, except for the `Vector<LSA> lsaArray`...

---

Edit: I also tried sending a third `sendMessage(SOSPFPacket.HELLO)` after `_router.propagateSynchronization(message.lsaInitiator, message.srcIP);`. This time, the message being sent contains two `LSA`, the first one having two `LinkDescription`, the second one having one. Both `LSA` are received by the server, but still, only the first `LinkDescription` is received in the first `LSA`. The message id is correct in all three messages.
If I run everything a second time (i.e. I create a new Client and a new ClientService Thread for the already running routers), only then does the server finally receive two `LinkDescription` in the first `LSA`.

Comment: The code corrects serializes and deserializes. Please show how you send the objects. How do you initialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java sends references to objects that have already been serialized, to preserve the integrity of object graphs.

You should call `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` after each `writeObject()`.

Or use `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`, but note that it still shares referenced objects, i.e. if you try to send a list with both added and changed element objects, it will send the new list and new element objects, but not the element objects which have been changed.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks so much for the fix and explanation. I wish I could upvote your answer, but I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Somehow it seems like the problem was the following line of code in `Util.makeMessage`: `rd.getLsd().getStore().forEach((k, v) -> message.lsaArray.addElement(v));`. I replaced it with `rd.getLsd().getStore().forEach((k, v) -> message.lsaArray.add(new LSA(v)));` with the following LSA constructor:

```
public LSA(LSA lsa) {
  linkStateID = lsa.linkStateID;
  lsaSeqNumber = lsa.lsaSeqNumber;
  links = new LinkedList<>();
  for (LinkDescription ld : lsa.links) {
    LinkDescription linkD = new LinkDescription();
    linkD.linkID = ld.linkID;
    linkD.portNum = ld.portNum;
    linkD.tosMetrics = ld.tosMetrics;
    links.add(linkD);
  }
}
```

In other words, I needed to deep copy the object contained in my message.

Comment: I am not entirely sure why I needed to deep copy the entire object to make it work. I think Java serialization passes objects by reference over TCP, so my guess is that the server was receiving a reference to the first object it had already received. A proper explanation of this phenomenon would be appreciated, so I know when deep copy is needed.